# PyDev does not appear after install in eclipse7 though I have java7 in eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have java7 (jre7) and eclipse Mars.

I tried installing the pydev latest version in both the ways 1. Install new software 2. dropin

In both the ways, installation is successful but pydev is not listed in the preferences or while adding the projects.

Guys, please help.

Comment: You **did** restart Eclipse after installing pydev, did you? Does pydev show up in Help->Installation details->Plug-ins? Do you see any unusual console output if you start eclipse in a terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

I did restart and checked the pydev but no luck.I could not see the pydev in the plugin section. But seeing this in Installed Software section.

I have been using the java 7 only.

I am in windows hence not able to run it in terminal window!